# Powershell - Exchange calendar sharing looping through all users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

What I would like to do is get a list of all users in exchange and loop through them giving each user full access ("owner") right to every other **calendar**. So basically I want everyone at the company to have "owner" permission to everyone else.

Here is what I have to far it works fine but I would like this to be automated meaning the "username1" and "username2" to be replaced with active users from my exchange server.

**Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "username1":\calendar -user "username2" -AccessRights owner**

Comment: You have lots of options but you can use `Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object{Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "username1":\calendar -user $_.SamAccountName -AccessRights owner}` That should work. Be careful as you are making changes to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment on the question.

You have lots of options but you can use

```
Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object{Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "username1":\calendar -user $_.SamAccountName -AccessRights owner}
```

This will grab every mailbox, since no filter is applied, and add the MailboxFolderPermission to those mailboxes.

That should work. **Be careful as you are making irreversable changes to everyone.**